# Experience Manager with DD4T

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, dd4t

We are using Tridion 2013 and DD4T-JAVA(spring MVC). Business requirement is to use Experience manger(XPM). Can we use DD4T Version 2.0.1 or only 2.0.2 is supported or recommended. Please share views on same. TIA

Answer (score 2):

Check the DD4T github page and release notes.

- **dd4t-2-java** Current stable version: 2.0.1-beta

  so you can use this version.

if its new implementation, try DXA which gives you XPM support in mvc application without much effort.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run XPM with every version of DD4T java. The SiteEdit package from the dd4t-example-site project will offer the necessary api. (Note that SiteEdit is the old name of XPM).